# Abstracting the mouse click listener in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

So far I have something like the following, where each button on a page is given a unique ID (one, two, three, etc):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(doThing);
    $("#two").click(doThing);
    $("#three").click(doThing);
    $("#four").click(doThing);
});

function doThing(){
    $("#textbox").prepend("<p>Clicked " + this.id + "</p>");
}
```

Is there a way to condense down the growing list of click listeners, so I don't have to repeat myself for each button, while still returning the appropriate ID?

Comment: Use class, or target 'button' element in selector...

Comment: [**Class Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a beginner question for sure but there's code and a real question.

Comment: yep, this is not a good downvote -> shame on you mister "i know everything"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a class to all the elements that will have the click applied to.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".do-thing-el").click(function(){
         $("#textbox").prepend("<p>Clicked " + this.id + "</p>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="do-thing-el" id="one">Something</p>
<p class="do-thing-el" id="two">Else</p>
<p class="do-thing-el" id="three">Goes</p>
<p class="do-thing-el" id="four">Here</p>
<hr />
<div id="textbox"> <div>
```

Comment: I feel incredibly daft for not considering this... Thanks.